# In Angular UI (bootstrap based) what event is raised when a date picker is exited?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to build a custom datetimepicker directive nased on [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and I need to take some action whenever the user dismisses the standard date picker.  So, the steps are:

1. User clicks into (`focus`) the `input` that is the datepicker and the little calendar pops up.
2. The user either selects a date or clicks outside of the calendar and the calendar closes.

Is there an Angular event that I can hook in to for #2 regardless of whether the user selected a date or whether they just clicked outside of the calendar?

As a side note, I am also using jQuery and have attempted to just access the `input`'s `blur` event.  This works, but not with the desired results because clicking on any of the buttons within the calendar pop up (such as scrolling from month to month) will trigger the code associated with the blur event and that is not what I want.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can watch the `is-open` attribute in your controller. When it gets a `false` value, this means that it is closed.

Comment: Thanks, but unless I am doing this wrong, `is-open` is set by my code, and not by any internal Angular functions so it still isn't giving me any feedback as to the actual state of the popup.  In other words, 'is-open' remains set to 'true' regardless of if the user selects a date, etc.  I would like to set it to 'false', but I need to know the event in which I can do that.

Comment: `is-open` is two way binded variable. You can either set it yourself to open the calendar prpgrammatically, but it is also set by the directive itself, ie when you focus, click or select a date to close.
You can print it like {{isopen}} to see it's status changes.

Comment: Okay, thanks again.  Here is the problem I run into, since I am making a directive which may be used multiple times on a single page, using the method you suggest would open all of the calendar controls at once.

Comment: You can create dynamic variables for `is-open` the same way you create the various instances of your directive. Anyway, I don't think I can help more on this, since the question is how to "catch" that calendar is closed. If you want more help, you have to provide a plunker!